# Firebase Database Rules read problems

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have problems with read permission.
It will be helpfull if someone help me.

Note: the authentification work the user is loged...

Write permissions work but read permissions are denied.

**I have this code:**

```
{
  "rules": {
      "user":{
            "$uid":{
                    ".read":  "auth.uid==$uid", // i try with ===
                    ".write": "auth.uid==$uid" //  i try with ===
                   }
                 }
            }
}
```

This is the javascript code:

```
var userRef= db.ref().child("user/"+id);

userRef.on('child_added', data=>{
console.log(data.val());
});

userRef.on('child_changed', data=>{
console.log(data.val());
});

userRef.on('child_removed', data=>{
console.log(data.val());
});

function insertUser(){

 db.ref("user/"+id).set({
     email:email,
     name:name
 });
}
```

I also try with:

```
This make me a error on JavaScript
var userRef= db.ref("user").child(id);
```

I put **".read": true**, but nothing happen yet!

I get the id in that way:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
function(user){
     if (user) {
           if (user != null) {
             user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
                 name = profile.displayName;
                 email = profile.email;
                 photoUrl = profile.photoURL;

                id=user.uid;
                var img = document.querySelector('#simg');
                var p = document.querySelector('#p');
                img.src=photoUrl;
                p.innerHTML=name;
                pemail.innerHTML=email;
             });
         }
     }
```

Thanks!

Comment: how you get the id ?

Comment: What error are you facing on `db.ref("user").child(id);`?

Comment: i'll put in the question, give me a second!

Comment: the error is **undefine!** but when i call the id in the console the value it's displayed

Comment: Sounds a javascript problem. I recommend you to set a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y910x2vw/) so people can understand whats happening.

Comment: you know is a firebase-web-app i can't do my proyect keys! @adolfosrs

Comment: if someone wants i could send a invitation for enter at firebase console with some privileges

Comment: Would be nice if I had the jsFiddle. I'm guessing, but I think the `id` isnt set when you define you `userRef`, so you won't be able to read something that does not exist. I suppose your read would work if you set the ref inside your `onAuthStateChanged` right after you set the id.

Comment: i did! but it was the same error. id has data i know cuz this  work: **`var userRef= db.ref().child("user/"+id);`** but i have to put the rules as default. if you have time i can invite you to the proyect just give me you email

Comment: @adolfosrs it is javascript problem. but i tryed diferents way and nothing. i put a static Userid and works. after that i declared de id with this value an after the user get loged i change for the current Userid but it doesnt work! do you have any idea to do?